# Mover un elemento cuando otro este en focus

Tags: css, html5

Quiero mover un label cuando un input este seleccionado son la pseudo-clase ":focus" en css. Según yo el código esta bien pero no me lo mueve. Siento que el problema puede ser en el simbolo "~" puede que no lo reconozca porque cuando selecciono solo el elemento para que se cambie el borde de color si lo cambia.

```
<div id="arriba2">
    <label for="input" id="label">Ingresa tu contraseña</label>
    <input type="password" name="input" id="input">
</div>

#arriba2{
        width: 100%;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;

        #label {
            position: absolute;
            margin-top: 87px;
            left: 55px;
            z-index: 1;
            color: #685f5f;
            pointer-events: none;
            transition: .3s;
        }
        
        #input {
            width: 81%;
            height: 52px;
            outline: none;
            border: 1px solid #dadce0;
            border-radius: 4px;
            position: relative;
            margin-top: 70px;
            padding: 10px;
        }

        #input:focus ~ #label, #input:valid ~ #label {
            color: red;
            transform: translateY(150%);
        }
        

        #input:focus{
            border: 2px solid #1b66c9;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ya que tu código es HTML + CSS, puedes colocarlo como _snippet_ (con el botón que indica `<>`). Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes 2 problemas:

1.- `#input:focus ~ #label`

Este selector selecciona a `#label` que sea hermano de `#input:focus`, pero la lectura es hacia abajo. Es decir los hermanos de `#input:focus` que van abajo en el HTML (no arriba)

La solución es intercambiar los elementos HTML de lugar. Colocando el `input` primero y luego el `label`

```
<input type="password" name="input" id="input">
<label for="input" id="label">Ingresa tu contraseña</label>
```

---

2.- El otro problema es `#input:valid`. No le has agregado validación a tu input, por lo que siempre será `valid`. Pienso que debes colocar como mínimo el atributo `required` y quizás el `minlength`

```
<input type="password" name="input" id="input" minlength="8" required>
```

```css
#arriba2{
        width: 100%;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        position:relative;

#label {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 87px;
    left: 55px;
    z-index: 1;
    color: #685f5f;
    pointer-events: none;
    transition: .3s;
}

#input {
    width: 81%;
    height: 52px;
    outline: none;
    border: 1px solid #dadce0;
    border-radius: 4px;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 70px;
    padding: 10px;
}

#input:focus ~ #label, #input:valid ~ #label {
    color: red;
    transform: translateY(150%);
}


#input:focus{
    border: 2px solid #1b66c9;
}
}
```

```html
<div id="arriba2">
    <input type="password" name="input" id="input" minlength="8" required>
    <label for="input" id="label">Ingresa tu contraseña</label>
</div>
```